# Async array without using anything async?

Tags: angularjs

It drives me crazy. I have a really simple "problem" and it took me hours and still have no idea whats going on.

I have a child service which inherits from a parent service (I'm using ES6). The constructor takes an 1 argument called `options`. `options` will be assigned to `this._defaults`.

Now before I pass the `options` into my object (`new Service(options)`) I populate `options` with some data. To keep it simple, my current `options` object looks like this:

```
const options = {
  types: []
}
```

Now I add some stuff into the types array, like this:

```
const Types = {
  standard: {
    some: 'data'
  },
  freeroll: {
    some: 'data'
  },
  mainevent: {
    some: 'data'
  },
  qualifier: {
    some: 'data'
  }
};

angular.forEach(Types, (val, key) => {
  options.types[key] = true;
});
```

I assign my service to the scope like this:

```
$scope.service = new Service(options)
```

and output the service using console. The console now says the value of `_defaults.types` is `Array(0)`. When I click on the array the correct values will be shown but the scope is not aware of that.

How is that? Doesn't `Array(0)` mean that at the time of the console.log() the array wasn't filled with any values but has been later? Like an async function would do?

[Here is a plunk of my problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/xuFUobXjXom84eNDogvO?p=preview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `types` is an array and you're treating it like a plain Object. You can solve this one of two ways.

First just change `types` to an Object:

```
const options = {
  types: {}
};
```

Or, if you need an Array, change how you're adding items to the array:

```
angular.forEach(Types, (val, key) => {
  options.types.push({
      type: key,
      value: val
  });
});
```

Note that this is just one way of turning the object into an array, the data structure you end up with is up to you.

Comment: That's true. It should be mentioned that it's just how JSON.stringify works, which is used by json filter internally.

Comment: Well what should I say. It's such an easy mistake and I didn't see it. Totally makes sense, thank you.

Comment: no problem--when you look at code too long (especially you're own) it's hard to see the little killers like brackets vs braces